# Tensoflow Model.fit adds extra dimension when training with custom model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I made [this colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/antoineneidecker/9f43ec22d9f8ee5e729c321a352ef4e9/model-fit-creating-extra-dimension.ipynb) so that you can play around with the code.

tldr;
The shape of my `x_data` is `(# of examples, 12, 1, 100, 1 )` and when the data is passed to the model, the shape of each example becomes `(None, 12, 1, 100, 1 )`. How do I get rid of the None?

---

I'm trying to train a series of examples with the following data structure:

```
import numpy as np

x_train = np.reshape(np.random.rand(200, 12, 100),(200, 12, 1, 100, 1)) #X training data (see dimensions in output)
y_train =  np.random.rand(200, 20) #Y training data (see dimensions in output)
n_class = np.shape(y_train)[1] #Number of classes in the classification task

print(np.shape(x_train))
print(np.shape(y_train))
____________
(200, 12, 1, 100, 1)
(200, 20)
```

x_train dimensions explained:

- There are 200 examples. Each x_train example has a corresponding y_train example with a one-hot encoded 20 dim vector representing the class it belongs to.
- Each example contains 12-time series. Each time series is 100 units long and we want to convolve over them separately.
- We have shaped each time series as (1, 100, 1) because of the [Conv1D keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D).
- As per the link above, the input dimensions should be: (batch_size, (steps, input_dim))

  batch_size = 1,
  steps = 100,
  input_dim = 1

The model is as follows (it can also be found [in the colab](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/antoineneidecker/9f43ec22d9f8ee5e729c321a352ef4e9/model-fit-creating-extra-dimension.ipynb)):

```
def custom_model(x_data, n_class):
    """
    This is the custom model used to convolve over the data
    We want to convolve over each dimension independently
    """
    conv_inputs = []
    conv_outputs = []
    amount_of_filters = np.shape(x_data[0])[0] 
    # Let's create a separate convolution channel for each one of the dims in x_data
    for i in range(amount_of_filters):
        x0 = keras.Input(batch_shape=(1, 100, 1))
        # conv_inputs will therefore have a size of (12, 1, 100, 1)
        conv_inputs.append(x0)
        x0 = Conv1D(filters=20,kernel_size=10,strides=2,padding="same",data_format="channels_last")(x0)
        x0 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=6, data_format="channels_last")(x0)
        x0 = Conv1D(filters=20, kernel_size=4, padding="same", data_format="channels_last")(x0)
        x0 = MaxPool1D(pool_size=3, data_format="channels_last", padding="same")(x0)
        x0 = Flatten()(x0)
        x0 = Dense(100, activation="relu")(x0)
        x0 = Dropout(0.2)(x0)
        x0 = Dense(10, activation="relu")(x0)
        conv_outputs.append(x0)
    # Convolving all outputs from the above convolutions. 
    x1 = concatenate(conv_outputs)
    x1 = Dense(100, activation="relu")(x1)
    x1 = Dense(100, activation="relu")(x1)
    out = Dense(n_class)(x1)

    modelConv = keras.Model(inputs=conv_inputs, outputs=out)

    return modelConv
```

When running the model:

```
model = custom_model(x_train, n_class)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=250, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
```

The following error comes up:

```
ValueError: Layer model expects 12 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors. Inputs received: [<tf.Tensor 'IteratorGetNext:0' shape=(None, 12, 1, 100, 1) dtype=float32>]
```

You can see that the input shape is (None, 12, 1, 100, 1 ). How do I get rid of the None? As shown above, when printing the shape of x_train, the None dimension does not appear.
My question is how do I feed in the x_data with each example being (12, 1, 100, 1) dimensional?

Thank you!